# Best way to choose users to email?

Tags: 7, entities, rules, emails

I have a content type of things to be worked on. I want to be able to select which user is responsible for a certain project. Then use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to email them with other various conditions and action sets.

What is the best way to create a field in this content type that will change dynamically by the users with certain criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module it is possible .

> - A generic entity reference field
> - Four widgets:
> - Two implemented on top of the Options module (Select and    Radios/Checkboxes),
> - Two autocomplete widgets (one with one text field per entry, one    tag-style with comma-separated entries in the same text field)
> - Two formatters:
> - A "Label" formatter, with optional link that displays the label of    the referenced entity (the node title, the user name, etc.)
> - A "Rendered entity" formatter, that renders the references entity    using a configurable view mode

Add field in your content type of user entity reference then it is automatically select value of user for emails

Comment: That worked perfectly as far as creating a field in the content type that was generated by a Entity Reference based View!  One issue I am having is not able to send the email when it gets passed in the email address from the Entity Reference field.  I had this same issue when testing it by sending the email address just from a list (text) widget.  Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Use of [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) module with [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) will be more better for you.

Comment: Ya perfect!  Chosen really helps out to create an easy way of selecting!